# How to use django-treebeard in Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-treebeard

I am trying to use django-treebeard in the admin section.

from https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/intro.html#configuration

> Note: If you are going to use the Treeadmin class, you need to add the
>   path to treebeard’s templates in TEMPLATE_DIRS. Also you need to
>   enable django.core.context_processors.request in the
>   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in your django settings file.

so I have added my tree in admin.py and it shows up in the admin, but when I click on it I get

> 'adminmedia' is not a valid tag library: Template library adminmedia
>   not found, tried

how do I find where the treebeard templates are? Will it be dynamic for production? 
Also I don't have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in my settings.py file.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a problem with treebeard not supporting django 1.5, there has been fixes and the beta release is ready, you can update it through pypi:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-treebeard/django-treebeard-2.0b1.tar.gz